# pip install local package missed new functions

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have a Python library named `imgtoolkit` which I installed locally before. It provides 2 major functions: `find_duplicate()` and `find_blur()`. These functions work perfectly. Previously I used `pip install .` in the package root folder, where `setup.py` is located.

Today I added one more function `analyze_blur()` to the code. I uninstalled the local-installed package via `pip uninstall imgtoolkit` and re-install it via `pip install .`.

However, the new function cannot be found.

> AttributeError: module 'imgtoolkit.tools' has no attribute 'analyze_blur'

The test script looks like this:

```
from imgtoolkit import tools

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tools.analyze_blur() # raises AttributeError
    tools.find_blur() # works fine
```

What did I miss?

---

I also tried to update the release on PyPI (from v0.0.4 to v0.0.5), but the **same problem exists**. PyPI project page: https://pypi.org/project/imgtoolkit/

And the related source is at: https://github.com/shivanraptor/imgtoolkit/blob/master/imgtoolkit/tools.py (line 48 & 74)

Comment: Hard to guess... makes me think maybe 2 different Python interpreters are in play. `pip` installs for one Python interpreter, but a different Python interpreter is used to run the code. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: You're right. `python -m pip install` reports I'm using `v0.0.4` while `pip install` reports I'm using `v0.0.5`. How do I make these 2 commands loading the same list of libraries?

Comment: You need to make sure that the `pip` script is "attached" to the `python` binary. How to do it depends on the OS, how things are installed and so on. -- One sure thing is that `pip` is using a different Python interpreter than what `python` points to. You can check with `pip debug` and `python -m pip debug`.

Comment: executable path `pip debug` of `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9` (3.9.15) while `python -m pip debug` is `/Users/adv/opt/miniconda3/bin/python` (3.9.7). How can I configure them to be the same one?

Comment: I can not guess, I do not know your system and how it is setup. This is beyond the scope of StackOverflow. -- Maybe it is an issue with `PATH` environment variable, maybe it is something more involved. I think that in your case I would reinstall things from scratch.